# DataSnapshot is missing a constructor with no arguments

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am implementing Firebase Recyclerview UI in my application. I have implemented a recyclerview adapter and it shows me following exception. 
Following is my adapter code :

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataSnapshot, MyHolder> recyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataSnapshot, MyHolder>(
                DataSnapshot.class,
                R.layout.row_slots,
                MyHolder.class,
                databaseReference.child("slots").child(uid).child(dayOfWeek).child("time")
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MyHolder viewHolder, DataSnapshot model, int position) {

                System.out.println("Key : "+model.getKey());

            }

        };
```

It is showing following exception : 
[image]

How can I get a snapshot value using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Comment: You must define your own model class.

Comment: Yes I have made like that. But with my own model class I cannot be able to get key of each node as we can get from snapshot. That's why I am trying with Snapshot. Is there any way in which we can get key of node with our own Class.(Without storing key as child for that node)

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding. Lets assume there is one node users. Everytime I add new user I use method push(). Now user has two child name and email. So for retrieving I have created one User.class with two fields name and email. Everything works fine. But what if I want to retrieve push id of that user. Using snapshot we can get that but using User.class we cannot get that beacuse there is no child in user node contains push id.

Comment: Your answer is correct but it won't fulfill my situation.

Comment: take a look at my final update the last code snippet is giving you the push Id @Dhaval

Comment: @jankigadhiya  Yes It is working. But I already knew that using ValueEvent or ChieldEvent. I was looking for that same thing using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. I can't get SnapShot in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter that is what I am asking. Your snippet is right but it is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser (and author of the FirebaseUI adapters) here*

Lots of good answers already. I'd indeed typically recommend creating a Java class that represents your data objects.

But if you're intent on using a `DataSnapshot`, you can override `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot` to handle the "conversion":

```
@Override
protected ChatMessage parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot;
}
```

Comment: @Dhaval If it's Puf and it's about Firebase, you should definitely look into it.

Comment: @Frank Thank you. This is what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is `DataSnapShot` is **missing a no Argument** Constructor so you can not use it directly like this.

> **Use some other model class instead.**

Like this :

Create your own model called `FriendlyMessage` :

```
public class FriendlyMessage {

private String text;
private String name;

// Created constructor with no Arguments 
public FriendlyMessage() {
}

public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name) {
    this.text = text;
    this.name = name;       
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

> **Most important** thing we have created **constructor with no Arguments**
>   which was missing in `DataSnapShot`

**NOTE :** The above model class is just an example for you as you are new in firebase. You can have your own model class with your own type of parameters and all.

The use it like this for your Firebase Recyclerview :

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MyHolder>(
                    FriendlyMessage.class,
                    R.layout.row_slots,
                    MyHolder.class,
                    databaseReference.child("slots").child(uid).child(dayOfWeek).child("time")) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MyHolder viewHolder, FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage, int position)
        {

        }
    };
```

**EDIT :**

> It also matter how you are pushing the data on Database. Do it
>   directly with your model class.

For example for above model `FriendlyMessage` push it like this :

```
FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage("message", "Username");
databaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
```

Here your `child()` will be somewhat different from my implementation it is just an example.

**For Listening to a particular DataSnapShot :**

```
databaseReference.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //The PUSH ID OP WANTED

                System.out.println("Push Id ---"+postSnapshot.getKey()); 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    })
```

> Explaining the above listener. It will give you the `DataSnapShot`
>   Object for your every user who is falling inside your child "users". **You can access Push id by `getKey()` method.**

Comment: can u set a example how to push id thanks inside ondatachange

Answer (score 3):

When initializing your `recyclerAdapter`, your passing a `DataSnapshot.class` as your `modelClass`, wherein a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) doesn't really have a Constructor with no parameters which I think is causing the error, also I think that makes a `DataSnapshot` an invalid `modelClass`.

As stated in the [FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/index.html?com/firebase/ui/FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter.html) for the `modelClass`:

> modelClass - Firebase will marshall the data at a location into an instance of a class that you provide

You should define your own `modelClass` by creating an object that suites your needs. There's a simple example on the `FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter` link that you can check out. Cheers!

---

**EDIT**:

As per the comments, I suggested to have your own modelClass object have a `DataSnapshot` as a parameter. For a simple example of what I'm saying, refer below.

```
public class ModelClass {

        String sampleString;

        ModelClass() {
        }

        ModelClass(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Do what you need from the dataSnapshot here
            sampleString = dataSnapshot.child("").toString();
        }

    }
```

I think from the example above, you would get what I mean. **BUT**, I'm not sure if this is recommended nor if it's even acceptable. I haven't tried this out before so I'm also not sure if it'll work.

Since this concern is actually different from the one posted. I suggest posting a different one if ever it doesn't work. Happy Coding. Cheers!

Comment: Yes I have made like that. But with my own model class I cannot be able to get key of each node as we can get from snapshot. That's why I am trying with Snapshot. Is there any way in which we can get key of node with our own Class.(Without storing key as child for that node)

Comment: You could make your `modelClass` have a `DataSnapshot` parameter, and do the parsing/retrieving of the values from the dataSnapshot from there. :)

Comment: Can you help me with that please. Is there any example or can you provide me any example?

Comment: That was just a suggestion from out of the blue, I haven't really tried it out before. But I'll give an example of what's on my mind.

Comment: It would be helpful. :)