# How to know the random id given to a firebase data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My problem is that I can't retrieve the random key generated by `Firebase` when saving data (I'm obliged to use that random key), for example

[image]

I tried to use `dataSnapshot.getKey()`, but it didn't work,any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: could you attach the entire code you are trying?

Comment: see this question : [DataSnapshot is missing a constructor with no arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144597/datasnapshot-is-missing-a-constructor-with-no-arguments/38144987#38144987)

Answer (score 6):

According to your problem you could use this:

For Android:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("posts");
String key =  myRef.push().getKey();           //this returns the unique key generated by firebase

myRef.child(key).child("author").setValue("gracehop");//this creates the reqs key-value pair
myRef.child(key).child("title").setValue("Announcing COBOL");//this creates the reqs key-value pair
```

For Web Dev:

```
var messageListRef = firebase.database().ref('posts');
var newMessageRef = messageListRef.push();
newMessageRef.set({
 'author': 'gracehop',
 'title': 'Announcing COBOL'
});
```

Comment: Dear sir, may i know how to use "String key =  myRef.push().getKey();" in php ? (i am trying to insert data by using php so)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
String key = ref.push().getKey();
ref.child(key).setValue(post);
```

Hope this answers your question :)

[Firebase - Save Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve random key then  you should use `addChildEventValueListerner` because it gives u child of the *posts* node one by one.

```
 FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 DatabaseReference mref = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
 mref.child("posts").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
              if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                 String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
              }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know any of the field's data, say you know the author's name then you can retrieve the key/keys(if multiple author has same name). It is describe here very clearly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38232280/5129997