# How to get the key from the value in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I get the key "-KLpcURDV68BcbAvlPFy" when I know the field "name" contains "efg" in the following structure in Firebase.

```
clubs
    -KLpcURDV68BcbAvlPFy
        dept: "abc"
        desc: "xyz"
        name: "efg"
    -asdasdasddsad
        dept: "asda"
        desc: "asd"
        name: "adddd"
```

I tried this but it returned "clubs"

```
mDatabase.child("clubs").orderByChild("name").equalTo("efg").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String clubkey =dataSnapshot.getKey();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's because you're using a `ValueEventListener`. If the query matches multiple children, it returns a list of all those children. Even if there's only a single matches child, it's still a list of one. And since you're calling `getKey()` on that list, you get the key of the location where you ran the query.

To get the key of the matches children, loop over the children of the snapshot:

```
mDatabase.child("clubs")
         .orderByChild("name")
         .equalTo("efg")
         .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String clubkey = childSnapshot.getKey();
```

But note that if you assume that the club name is unique, you might as well store the clubs under their name and access the correct one without a query:

```
mDatabase.child("clubs")
         .child("efg")
         .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String clubkey = dataSnapshot.getKey(); // will be efg
```

Answer (score 6):

If anyone needs to do this using Kotlin:

```
mDatabase.child("clubs")
        .orderByChild("name")
        .equalTo("efg")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                dataSnapshot.children.forEach {
                     //"it" is the snapshot
                     val key: String = it.key.toString()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    //do whatever you need
            }
         })
```

Answer (score 3):

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("clubs");

mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String key = ds.getKey();
        }
    }
｝
```

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out a very easy way to do this. You need to get the auto-generated key before you send it to firebase. So for my project I did something like the following:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var rootRef = database.ref();
var autoId = rootRef.push().key
rootRef.child(autoId).set({
key: value,
key: value,
key: value,
autoid: autoId
})
```

Now when i go to my child added function and take a snapshot, I can easily get to `snapshot.val().autoid` and store it in a variable or as a button attribute so that I can delete it later.

Answer (score 0):

If this key (asdasdasddsad) also had the name:"efg" will club key will become asdasdasddsad and KLpcURDV68BcbAvlPFy

Comment: Above post should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

We can use HashMap.

initialize:

> String for storing Key value. ModelClass for storing you data.

```
val hashMap: HashMap<String, "Your Model Class"> = hashMapOf()
databaseReference.child("/Product").orderByChild("ProductName")
        .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                /*p0.children.mapNotNullTo(models) { it.getValue(ProductModel::class.java) }.run {

                }*/
                p0.children.forEach {
                    val value = it.getValue(ProductModel::class.java) as ProductModel
                    hashMap[it.key!!] = value
                }.run { adp.update(hashMap) }
            }
        })
```

after this we can also get key & its value by using (index)

> 5 is Index

```
hashMap.keys.elementAt(5)
hashMap.values.elementAt(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it in Kotlin

```
var ref  = database.child("clubs")
val database_listener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val key = ds.key
           }
        }
     }
   ref.addValueEventListener(database_listener)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in Java** **(100% working!)**:

```
//firebase reference
DatabaseReference  mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

//set THe_strOX's database contents from the question
mRef.child("clubs").child("-KLpcURDV68BcbAvlPFy").child("dept").setValue("abc");
mRef.child("clubs").child("-KLpcURDV68BcbAvlPFy").child("desc").setValue("xyz");
mRef.child("clubs").child("-KLpcURDV68BcbAvlPFy").child("name").setValue("efg");
mRef.child("clubs").child("-asdasdasddsad").child("dept").setValue("asda");
mRef.child("clubs").child("-asdasdasddsad").child("desc").setValue("asd");
mRef.child("clubs").child("-asdasdasddsad").child("name").setValue("adddd");
//

mRef.child("clubs").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
    {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
        {
            String pushkey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            mRef.child("clubs").child(pushkey).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
                {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                    {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getKey().toString().equals("name")) {
                            //edit efg to any desired value
                            if (dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().equals("efg")) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, pushkey, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) { }
                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @androidx.annotation.Nullable String previousChildName) { }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) { }
    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @androidx.annotation.Nullable String previousChildName) { }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
});
```

}