# How can I get the Key from my Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the `id` from Firebase, I am build android app using Java

[image]

Comment: You'll need to be keeping the key you need in the `Upload` class in order to be able to look it up in your click listener.

Answer (score 2):

Putting suggestion by [Sir Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) in action -

You can get key value from documentSnapShot -

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    String docuementKey = documentSnapshot.getReference().getId();

    //toast message 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), docuementKey, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

then you can save it in your Upload POJO.

Happy Coding !

Comment: thanks for the answer Nikhil Sharma but the issue is I need to get key from database not on Firestore :(

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), docuementKey, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` will give you the key value you have marked red on your question image, and if Firebase Firestore is not your database then which database you are referring to ?

Comment: I want to get the key from My Firebase Database, not from Firestore, yes my companyName and imageUrl is from Firestore, but I need to get the KEY from FIREBASE DATABASE, thanks for your Response Nikhil Sharma I really appreciate it, Thank you, Still waiting for the response Sir Nikhil

Comment: could you post a screen shot distinguishing  FIREBASE DATABASE KEY and FIRESTORE KEY, according to your understanding of both and are you referring to [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore)

Comment: Yes I'm referring to Firebase Realtime database. thank you Nikhil, thumbs up to you, I need to get the key of my Realtime database

Comment: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("your_document_path").getId()` .. have you try that ?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232140/how-to-get-the-key-from-the-value-in-firebase) thread as well...